# How to color numbers in php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am developing a portfolio as a project to learn PHP and JavaScript. I have the stock price updating every minute but I would like to make it go green or red depending if it is going up or down. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you expect people to not downvote and/or close your question, you should explain what you've tried and post any code relative to this problem

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS

Comment: How do you store the *price* in the database? Assuming you store it in a database..

Comment: How are you checking the stock price, via AJAX?

Comment: I have not tried anything. I have no idea how it is done so I am looking for guidance or an example. Anything to point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. I am getting the stock price with AJAX.

Comment: Could you post your code that currently gets the stock price via ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Look into applying CSS on the element containing the stock price. This can be done dynamically using Javascript. You can tell whether it has gone up or down by keeping a record of the last value and comparing it to the new. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that as followed:

1. Put the number in a e.g. div
2. Get the new number via ajax
3. Look if the new number is < , === or > than the current
4. Style the div

Answer (score 0):

This is not to complicated with a little CSS and some JavaScript. Here is a basic example. This could be done in a number of different ways. This is just one approach.

**CSS:**

```
.green {color:green;}
.red {color:red;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="stock-value green">12</span>
```

**JavaScript (using jQuery):**

```
if( $('.stock-value').text() > 0) {
   $('stock-value').addClass('green');
}
else if($('.stock-value').text() < 0){
    $('stock-value').addClass('red');
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/XakPM/